Retroarch USB Controller stops working on content load
I have a USB controller that I'm using with my Android phone.  On all the menus the controller works fine. However, when I load any content the controller stops working.  If I unplug the controller and plug it back in the controller is recognized and it starts working again.
I have tried this with 2 different USB controllers and maybe 5 different cores.  The same thing happens every time.
I'm using the latest stable retroarch build.  I tried the nightly build but couldn't get any controllers to work at all so I went back to the stable build.
I also factory reset my android phone, installed all the latest updates, and it did not fix the problem.
Edit 1: This is with a Samsung S10 phone
Edit 2: It looks like it is controller dependent.  I bought a Backbone One controller and the problem does not happen.

Do you mean the controller stops working whenever you load a game in Retroarch? What model of phone are you using?
